# The syntax of the command is incorrect. make: *** [bin/SC.class] Error 1

Tags: java, eclipse, cmd, makefile

I am trying to compile a project using the make command in cmd. My problem is that I gave this error:

> mkdir -p bin ; java -jar lib/jflex-1.6.1.jar -d src/ src/Lexer.lex ;
>   java -jar lib/java-cup-11b.jar -destdir src/ -parser Parser
>   src/Parser.cup ; javac -cp lib/java-cup-11b-runtime.jar -sourcepath
>   src/ -d bin/ src/SC.java The syntax of the command is incorrect. make:
>   *** [bin/SC.class] Error 1

and I'm not sure if it's a Makefile error or not. 
This is how my makeFile looks like:

```
LANG = SC
VERJFLEX = 1.6.1
VERCUP = 11b

all: bin/$(LANG).class ; 

bin/$(LANG).class: src/Lexer.lex src/Parser.cup src/$(LANG).java ; mkdir -p bin ; java -jar lib/jflex-$(VERJFLEX).jar -d src/ src/Lexer.lex ; java -jar lib/java-cup-$(VERCUP).jar -destdir src/ -parser Parser src/Parser.cup ; javac -cp lib/java-cup-$(VERCUP)-runtime.jar -sourcepath src/ -d bin/ src/$(LANG).java

TESTS = $(TESTCASES)
.PHONY: test $(TESTCASES) 
test: $(TESTCASES) ; echo done
$(TESTS):   
    echo $@ >> result.csv
    ./runTests.sh $(VERCUP) $(LANG) $@

clean:
    rm -rf src/Lexer.java src/Lexer.java~ src/sym.java src/Parser.java bin/*.class
```

Any idea where the problem might come from?
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are better build tools for Java than "make".

Comment: You appear to be trying to run a linux makefile, written for the linux shell , in the Windows shell (cmd).